# How to XOR two strings in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am making a programme to encrypt a message using a vegnier cypher.
But i am not sure what is wrong with it as when I xor the two variables it just outputs a question mark in a box any help will be appreciated.

```
    static string xor(string plaintext, string pad)
    {
        string cyphertext = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < (plaintext.Length); i++)
        {
            char p1 = Convert.ToChar(plaintext.Substring(i, 1));
            char c1 = Convert.ToChar(pad.Substring(i, 1));
            char ct1 = (char)(p1 ^ c1);
            cyphertext = cyphertext + (Convert.ToString(ct1));

        }
        return cyphertext;
    }
```

Comment: Before you start writing code it is good idea to understand what you want to achieve and how result will look like. At this point it is very unclear what you expect as output...

Comment: `'A' ^ 'A'` is 0.... Not a printable char.

Answer (score 2):

A single `xor` function would be enough when working with byte arrays, but if you want get a printable result you can use more intelligent codes....

```
var encstr = Enc("MyTextToHide", "MyKey");
var decstr = Dec(encstr, "MyKey");
```

---

```
static string Enc(string plaintext, string pad)
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pad);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(data.Select((b, i) => (byte)(b ^ key[i % key.Length])).ToArray());
}

static string Dec(string enctext, string pad)
{
    var data = Convert.FromBase64String(enctext);
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pad);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.Select((b, i) => (byte)(b ^ key[i % key.Length])).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code itself is likely working, the problem you are having is not all valid values for a `char` are printable characters. When you XOR the values you end up with a `char` that represents character that is unprintable for the console.

Answer (score 1):

Since resultant characters can well be *unprintable* (e.g. `'A' ^ 'A' == '\0'` - L.B. example  in the comments) I suggest *encoding* when outputing the 
encrypted string on the console. The routing itself:

```
static string xor(string plaintext, string pad) {
  // check for null, empty strings etc.
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(plaintext) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(pad))
    return plaintext;

  // Do not append string in the loop; use StringBuilder for this
  StringBuilder cyphertext = new StringBuilder(plaintext.Length);

  // You have no need in SubString and other stuff: just char xor char
  // i % pad.Length - if pad is shorter than plaintext
  for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.Length; ++i) 
    cyphertext.Append((char) (plaintext[i] ^ pad[i % pad.Length]));

  return cyphertext.ToString();
}
```

To show the text on the console let's represent each character as its unicode value `c => ((int) c).ToString("x4")`:

```
string test = "Quick brown fox";
string pad = "Pad";

Console.Write(string.Join(" ", xor(test, pad).Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4"))));
```

The output is

> **0001** **0014** **000d** 0033 **000a** 0044 0032 **0013** **000b** 0027 **000f**

Please, notice *command characters*